# QDoubleValidator and QLineEdit onEditFinished conflict?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm hoping to get some insight into a issue I'm facing using QDoubleValidator, I have created a widget to collect some information, and would like to have some fields validated as Double values, I have done so here:

```
orderform::orderform(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::orderform)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
this->setWindowTitle("Order Entry / Edt");
ui->edtOrderDate->setDate(QDate::currentDate()); //Sets date box to current date

//----- Validator for float input in 'money' fields -----//
auto dv = new QDoubleValidator(0.0,5.0,2);
ui->edtSoldFor->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtItemSubtotal->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtShipping->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtSalesTaxPFC->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtDiscount->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtOrderTotal->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtTotalFee->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtVAT->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtFeeIncVAT->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtBoughtFor->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtSupSubTotal->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtSupShipping->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtSupTax->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtSupOrderTotal->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtAddExpense->setValidator(dv);
ui->edtAddDiscount->setValidator(dv);
//-----         -----//
}
```

in addition each of these fields has a slot assigned to them to run a calculation when editing the field finishes, here is an example:

```
void orderform::on_edtSoldFor_editingFinished()
{
calcPltfrmOrderTotals();
}
```

and here is the function it calls:

```
void orderform::calcPltfrmOrderTotals() //This function is used to calculate all totals
{
//Var:
double valueAsDouble = 0;
QString valueAsString;

//Calc Order Sub Total
valueAsDouble = (ui->edtBoughtFor->text().toDouble() * ui->sbSupQty->value());
valueAsString = QString::number(valueAsDouble);
ui->edtSupSubTotal->setText(valueAsString);

//Calc Supplier Sub Total
valueAsDouble = (ui->edtSoldFor->text().toDouble() * ui->sbItemQty->value());
valueAsString = QString::number(valueAsDouble);
ui->edtItemSubtotal->setText(valueAsString);

//Calc Order Total on platform
valueAsDouble = ((ui->edtItemSubtotal->text().toDouble() + ui->edtShipping->text().toDouble() + ui->edtSalesTaxPFC->text().toDouble()) - ui->edtDiscount->text().toDouble());
valueAsString = QString::number(valueAsDouble);
ui->edtOrderTotal->setText(valueAsString);

//Calc fee total on platform
valueAsDouble = (ui->edtTotalFee->text().toDouble() + ui->edtVAT->text().toDouble());
valueAsString = QString::number(valueAsDouble);
ui->edtFeeIncVAT->setText(valueAsString);

//Calc Supplier Order Total
valueAsDouble = (ui->edtSupSubTotal->text().toDouble() + ui->edtSupShipping->text().toDouble() + ui->edtSupTax->text().toDouble());
valueAsString = QString::number(valueAsDouble);
ui->edtSupOrderTotal->setText(valueAsString);

//Calc PNL
valueAsDouble = (((ui->edtItemSubtotal->text().toDouble() - ui->edtFeeIncVAT->text().toDouble()) - ui->edtSupOrderTotal->text().toDouble())
                 - ui->edtAddExpense->text().toDouble()) + ui->edtAddDiscount->text().toDouble();
valueAsString = QString::number(valueAsDouble);
ui->lcdPNL->display(valueAsDouble);
};
```

the problem is before I added the validation to the fields, the calculations would run correctly and instantly after the edit finishes, but as soon as i add the validation the calculations on 'editfinish' is very hit and miss, sometime it works and other times it doesn't and i have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your validator range (0.0 to 5.0) is too narrow. If a newly calculated value falls outside the range, the validator state won't be `QValidator::Acceptable` anymore, and, as a side effect, the line edit will no longer emit the [editingFinished](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) signal.

You could try keeping the validator's `top()` to its default (infinity) value, maybe using the other constructor and using setters  to set decimals and range bottom:

```
auto dv = new QDoubleValidator();
dv->setDecimals(2);
dv->setBottom(0.0);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your response, and you are absolutely correct, after adjusting the Top, all my issues went away... I must have misunderstood how the to works